# NSString stringWithCString not showing special characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, character-encoding, nsstring

I'm using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",(unichar)decimalValueX];
```

but I have to call it thousands of times and its simply too slow.

As an alternative I tried this:

```
sprintf (cString, "%C", (unichar)decimalValueX);
[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

but no characters are correctly transalted.

If I try UTF8 instead of 16:

```
sprintf (cString, "%C", (unichar)decimalValueX);
[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I get alphanumeric, but I don't get foreign characters or other special characters.

Can anyone explain whats going on? Or how to make stringWithFormat faster?

Thanks!

Comment: You might include an example of the string with the special characters in your question...

Comment: From where you are getting string with special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `%C` format does not work with `sprintf` and related functions and non-ASCII characters. But there is a simpler method:
[`stringWithCharacters:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497248-stringwithcharacters?language=objc)
creates an `NSString` directly from a `unichar` array (UTF-16 code points).
For a single `unichar` this would be just

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&decimalValueX length:1];
```

Example:

```
unichar decimalValueX = 8364; // The Euro character
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&decimalValueX length:1];
NSLog(@"%@", string); // €
```

Example for multiple UTF-16 code points:

```
unichar utf16[] = { 945, 946, 947 };
NSString *string3 = [NSString stringWithCharacters:utf16 length:3];
NSLog(@"%@", string3); // αβγ
```

For characters outside of the "basic multilingual plane" (i.e.
characters > U+FFFF) you would have to use 2 UTF-16 code points
per character (surrogate pair).
Or use a different API like

```
uint32_t utf32[] = { 128123, 128121 };
NSString *string4 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:utf32 length:2*4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", string4); //
```

Comment: Using `NSInteger ` instead of `unichar` and `stringWithCharacters:(unichar*)...` might work better overall if the `length > 1`.

Comment: @l'L'l: I don't think so. The method expects a `unichar *` argument, pointing to `length` elements of type `unichar`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, use NSinteger for 8364, then cast unichar* in the stringWithCharacters: statement.

Comment: @l'L'l: But why? A unichar is a 16-bit integer. For characters > `U+FFFF` you have to pass an array of two `unichar` (surrogate pair). Or you use a different API (such as `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`).

Comment: For example using `unichar string = 83648362` would result in implicit conversion from 'int' to 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') changes value from 83648362 to 24426. Also If using `8364` and `length:2` then there will likely be garbage displayed at the end of the string. https://gist.github.com/dylib/c81d38b6fe684786f36bbacc058509ae

Comment: @l'L'l: This question (as I understand it) is about create a string from a single UTF-16 code point, because that is what the first line in the question does. If you have more than one then you have to pass an array: `unichar codes[] = { 8364, 8362 }; NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:codes length:2];`

Comment: It unclear if they are referring to a single code point or not, although I think using an array like you've just shown is likely the most versatile solution, since you could likely have any length > 1 and do `unichar codes[] = { 8364, 0 };` and still end up with the proper result. It might not work though for emoji or something such as that, which is what I was getting at with NSInteger.  :)

Comment: @l'L'l: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated the answer.

Comment: If it's a unicode codepoint, shouldn't this be a uint32_t with UTF32 encoding to ensure all 21 bits of Unicode fit?

Comment: @uliwitness: It won't make a difference (a signed 32-bit variable can hold all unsigned 21-bit numbers), but you are right, uint32_t is the proper type here, thanks for the feedback!